# PyGtk clipboard works only in python interactive mode

Tags: python, gtk

This is my `Python` script to see the data in the clipboard:

```
import gtk
import time

clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
print  clipboard.wait_for_targets()
def f(clipboard,selection,user_data):   print selection.data

clipboard.request_contents('STRING', f)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note that:

- I used the time.sleep(1) at the end to let Python have the time to call the callback function `f`.
- I can't use threads because these are problems with the packages `threads` and `gtk`.

The behaviours are:

- If I run `python` and copy this text it works.
- If I run `python thisscript.py` it doesn't works (the function `f` is never called)
- If I run `cat thisscript.py | python` it doesn't works (the function `f` is never called)

How could it happen? (and how could I fix it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running a GLib main loop: many GObject-based things may be broken if you do that. Try this instead of the sleep-loop:

```
gtk.mainloop()
```